# Re-usable Utility Methods in Digital Ocean Functions in Python

Tags: python, function, digital-ocean

I would like to be able to re-use code across multiple Digital Ocean Functions (their serverless tool).   I do not want to publish a library if I can avoid it.

I have tried a couple of approaches, but am willing to do about anything to get this to work.

### Approach 1.  Single File

My first attempt was using a single file with multiple Function entry points.

Under `packages/tom/` I have the file `tomsfns.py`:

```
def t1():
    return { "body", make_msg("T1") }

def t2():
    return { "body", make_msg("T2") }

def make_msg(caller):
    return "Hello " + caller
```

Dumb as toast, but should work fine. Under packages in the project.yml I have the following:

```
- name: tom
    functions:
      - name: tomsfns
        main: t1
        binary: false
        runtime: python:3.11
        web: false

      - name: tomsfns
        main: t2
        binary: false
        runtime: python:3.11
        web: false
```

What actually happens when you deploy that is you get one Function, `tom/tomsfns` and the entirety of the code in that single file.  What I hoped for was two Functions off the same codebase, even if they duplicated the code.

### Multi File

My second attempt was was to break out the desired utility into it’s own python file and then have separate files call it. This is the ‘style’ that makes the most sense to me but doesn’t work either.

Both the structure and the entirety of their contents are:

```
    packages
        rick
            r1.py
                 import make_msg
                 def main():
                    return { "body": make_msg("R1") }
            r2.py
                 import make_msg
                 def main():
                    return { "body": make_msg("R2") }
            rickutils.py
                 def make_msg(caller):
                    return "Hello " + caller
```

*(Begin: added after the original post)*

The relevant project.yml is:

```
    - name: rick
      functions:
       - name: r1
         runtime: python:3.11
         web: false

       - name: r2
         runtime: python:3.11
         web: false
```

*(End: Added after original post)*

This results in what appears to be the right structure and code in the published functions:

```
    Deployed functions ('doctl sls fn get <funcName> --url' for URL):
     - rick/r1
     - rick/r2
     - rick/rickutils
     - tom/tomsfns
```

However

- I didn’t want rickutils as a function
- More importantly the functions do not run.

`stderr: Invalid function: No module named 'make_msg'`

I have tried every combination of import statement and file location I can think of to get that method into the Function code but nothing has worked.

Does anybody have any thoughts or examples of this kind of thing?

Thanks.

Comment: I think the functions have to have different names in your YAML file

Comment: The name does appear to mean the name of the python file.   That would explain why the tom didn't work.  Which means I don't understand what the "main" entry does.    

That is I why went to Rick (the multifile style).    Documentations sure feels spotty for this stuff.

Comment: I've added the project.yml for the "Rick" attempt